# Circles in Swift - can't get rid of clipping

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I am working in Swift 3.0 and have used UIBezierPath to draw Circles. My code is below. No matter what I change, the edges of the circle are still clipped. The circles are in image views. I have tried manipulating the height/weight of the view, as well as changing it to "aspect fill" "aspect fit" "center" etc. A tutorial I watched also told me that if I change "var multiplier: CG Float = 1.0" to 0.85 or another number, the clipping will be gone. I have tried this and it did not work. How can I fix this?

```
class Circle1: UIView {
    var multiplier:CGFloat = 0.85
    //this takes away the "clippinh" you might see in the view

    var centerOfCirclesView: CGPoint{
        return CGPoint(x:bounds.midX, y:bounds.midY)
    }
    var halfOfViewsSize: CGFloat{
        return min(bounds.size.height, bounds.size.width) / 2
    }

    var lineWidth:CGFloat = 1.0

    //circle radius compute

    var full = CGFloat(M_PI * 2)
    var quarter = CGFloat(M_PI / 2)
    var half = CGFloat(M_PI)
    var threeQuarters = CGFloat(3 * M_PI / 2)


    func drawCircleCenteredAt(_:CGPoint, withRadius radius:CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath{
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerOfCirclesView,
                                      radius: halfOfViewsSize,
                                      startAngle: 00,
                                      endAngle: full,
                                      clockwise: false)
        circlePath.lineWidth = lineWidth

        return circlePath
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        UIColor(hue: 0.7194, saturation: 0, brightness: 0.52, alpha: 1.0).set()
        lineWidth = 15.0
        drawCircleCenteredAt(centerOfCirclesView, withRadius: halfOfViewsSize).stroke()
    }

}

class Circle2: UIView {

    var multiplier:CGFloat = 0.85
    //this takes away the "clippinh" you might see in the view

    var centerOfCirclesView: CGPoint{
        return CGPoint(x:bounds.midX, y:bounds.midY)
    }
    var halfOfViewsSize: CGFloat{
        return min(bounds.size.height, bounds.size.width) / 2
    }

    var lineWidth:CGFloat = 1.0

    //circle radius compute

    var full = CGFloat(M_PI * 2)
    var quarter = CGFloat(M_PI / 2)
    var half = CGFloat(M_PI)
    var threeQuarters = CGFloat(3 * M_PI / 2)


    func drawCircleCenteredAt(_:CGPoint, withRadius radius:CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath{
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerOfCirclesView,
                                      radius: halfOfViewsSize,
                                      startAngle: 00,
                                      endAngle: half,
                                      clockwise: false)
        circlePath.lineWidth = lineWidth

        return circlePath
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to reduce your radius either by multiplying by your 0.85 multiplier or by subtracting 0.5 * linewidth.

Comment: You should use `.pi` instead of `M_PI` in Swift 3

Answer (score 0):

You need to reduce your `radius` so that your circle is not clipped.  For example, in `Circle1`, pass in `halfOfViewSize - 0.5 * lineWidth` for the `radius` to `drawCircleCenteredAt(_:withRadius:)` and then use that radius when you create the `UIBezierPath`:

```
func drawCircleCenteredAt(_:CGPoint, withRadius radius:CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerOfCirclesView,
                                  radius: radius,               // Changed this to radius
                                  startAngle: 0,
                                  endAngle: full,
                                  clockwise: false)
    circlePath.lineWidth = lineWidth

    return circlePath
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    UIColor(hue: 0.7194, saturation: 0, brightness: 0.52, alpha: 1.0).set()
    lineWidth = 15.0
    drawCircleCenteredAt(centerOfCirclesView, withRadius: halfOfViewsSize - 0.5 * lineWidth).stroke()
}
```

Your `multiplier` is having no effect because you aren't using it anywhere.  You could also reduce your `radius` by using `halfOfViewSize * multiplier` when your create your `UIBezierPath`.

---

Here is the modified code which removes the setting of the colors and line widths from the `draw(_:)` routine.

```
class Circle1: UIView {
    var centerOfCirclesView: CGPoint{
        return CGPoint(x:bounds.midX, y:bounds.midY)
    }

    var halfOfViewsSize: CGFloat{
        return min(bounds.size.height, bounds.size.width) / 2
    }

    var lineWidth:CGFloat = 1.0

    var color = UIColor(hue: 0.7194, saturation: 0, brightness: 0.52, alpha: 1.0)
    //circle radius compute

    var full = CGFloat.pi * 2
    var quarter = CGFloat.pi / 2
    var half = CGFloat.pi
    var threeQuarters = 3 * CGFloat.pi / 2

    func drawCircleCenteredAt(_:CGPoint, withRadius radius:CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath{
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerOfCirclesView,
                                      radius: radius,                     // Changed this to radius
                                      startAngle: 0,
                                      endAngle: full,
                                      clockwise: false)
        circlePath.lineWidth = lineWidth

        return circlePath
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        color.set()
        drawCircleCenteredAt(centerOfCirclesView, withRadius: halfOfViewsSize - 0.5 * 15.0).stroke()
    }
}
```

Here is a demo that is running in a Swift Playground:

[image: Demo of overlapping circles in Swift Playground]

Comment: Everything looks great! however, now the smaller-width circle is not centered within the larger width circle. Do you know how to correct this?

Comment: I realized you probably do not know what that means.. the circle with the smaller width lays on top of the circle with the larger width. When it was clipped, it was centered, and now it is not. the outer border lines up with the other circle's outer border. any idea how to get it centered again? thanks!

Comment: You just need both circles to have the same radius.  So use the `lineWidth` from the thicker circle in the calculation of the `radius` for both circles.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, please accept it by clicking on the gray checkmark next to it to turn it green.